# Error while web scraping full job descriptions across multiple pages using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Would be great to get your help/ input on this!

I'm trying to scrape job info from indeed. Everything in the code was working fine until I tried to get full job descriptions *across multiple pages* using the job href. Now I keep getting the following error:

job_link = job_posts.find(name="a", class_="jcs-JobTitle").get("href")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Please find the code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Extract function
def extract(page):
    headers = {
        "User Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 \
        (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"}
    url = f"https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst+%C2%A330%2C000&l=London%2C+Greater+London&jt=fulltime&start={page}"
    r = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    return soup

# Transform function
def transform(soup):
    # Get list of all job_postings
    job_postings = soup.find_all(name="div", class_="slider_item")

    # Get job elements
    for job_posts in job_postings:
        job_title = job_posts.select_one("a span[title]").text
        company_name = job_posts.find(name="span", class_="companyName").text
        try:
            salary = job_posts.find(name="div", class_="salary-snippet").find("span").getText()
        except:
            salary = "n/a"
        summary_text = job_posts.find(name="div", class_="job-snippet").text.replace("\n", "")

        # full job descriptions
        job_link = job_posts.find(name="a", class_="jcs-JobTitle").get("href")
        absolute_link = 'https://uk.indeed.com' + job_link

        job_desc_r = requests.get(absolute_link)
        job_desc_data = job_desc_r.text
        job_desc_soup = BeautifulSoup(job_desc_data, "html.parser")

        full_description = [item.text for item in
                            job_desc_soup.find(name="div", class_="jobsearch-jobDescriptionText").find_all("li")]

    # Append jobs to job list 
        job = {
                'Job Title': job_title,
                'Company': company_name,
                'Salary': salary,
                'Summary': summary_text,
                'Full Descriptions': full_description
                }

        job_list.append(job)
    return


job_list = []

# Loop across multiple pages 
for page_num in range(0, 40, 10):
    extract_output = extract(page_num)
    transform(extract_output)
```

I've tried fixing the error using try and except (see below), but this has resulted in a lot of empty job descriptions.

```
# Get full job descriptions
        try:
            job_link = job_posts.find(name="a", class_="jcs-JobTitle").get("href")
        except:
            job_link = ""
        absolute_link = 'https://uk.indeed.com' + job_link

    # For each Job's webpage you need to connect to the link
        job_desc_r = requests.get(absolute_link)
        job_desc_data = job_desc_r.text
        job_desc_soup = BeautifulSoup(job_desc_data, "html.parser")

        try:
            full_description = [item.text for item in
                                job_desc_soup.find(name="div", class_="jobsearch-jobDescriptionText").find_all("li")]
        except:
            full_description = ""
```

Thank you in advance!
P.S. I'm using PyCharmCE on my mac

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the raw web scrape data, I am almost certain I understand why the error is occuring. It is highly likely that the anchor elements you are retrieving do not contain a 'link' in the `href` attribute.

HTML does not specify that `href` attributes are specifically for hyperlinks. For example, the `href` could be `href="this.classList.add("class")"` - such `href` contains no link.

Instead of creating columns for `job_posts` for all anchor elements, check if the `href` contains a valid hyperlink.

```py
if "http" in href:
  #execute code
  pass
```

Comment: Thanks! The href in the a-tag does have the hyperlink which, when joined with the 'https://uk.indeed.com' yields something like: https://uk.indeed.com/company/Kubrick-Group/jobs/Technical-Business-Analyst-1df3eb4df682d05f?fccid=d9926f2a37617c4e&vjs=3. However, the attribute error occurs when I try to get the href across multiple pages using the for loop.

Comment: @AlinaAZ just stabbing blindly here, is it possible that the link adds a `/page_number/` when the next page is looped?

Answer (score 0):

It means that there is no href attribute in the `<a>` tag, or actually that there is no `<a>` tag at all found.

You could use the `try/except` much the same way you used it for salary:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Extract function
def extract(page):
    headers = {
        "User Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 \
        (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"}
    url = f"https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst+%C2%A330%2C000&l=London%2C+Greater+London&jt=fulltime&start={page}"
    r = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    return soup

# Transform function
def transform(soup):
    # Get list of all job_postings
    job_postings = soup.find_all(name="div", class_="slider_item")

    # Get job elements
    for job_posts in job_postings:
        job_title = job_posts.select_one("a span[title]").text
        company_name = job_posts.find(name="span", class_="companyName").text
        print(company_name, job_title)
        try:
            salary = job_posts.find(name="div", class_="salary-snippet").find("span").getText()
        except:
            salary = "n/a"
        summary_text = job_posts.find(name="div", class_="job-snippet").text.replace("\n", "")

        # full job descriptions
        try:
            job_link = job_posts.find(name="a", class_="jcs-JobTitle").get("href")
            absolute_link = 'https://uk.indeed.com' + job_link
            job_desc_r = requests.get(absolute_link)
            job_desc_data = job_desc_r.text
            job_desc_soup = BeautifulSoup(job_desc_data, "html.parser")

            full_description = [item.text for item in
                                job_desc_soup.find(name="div", class_="jobsearch-jobDescriptionText").find_all("li")]
        
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            full_description = 'N/A'
            

    # Append jobs to job list 
        job = {
                'Job Title': job_title,
                'Company': company_name,
                'Salary': salary,
                'Summary': summary_text,
                'Full Descriptions': full_description
                }

        job_list.append(job)
    return


job_list = []

# Loop across multiple pages 
for page_num in range(0, 40, 10):
    extract_output = extract(page_num)
    transform(extract_output)
```

Comment: Thanks! I attempted to use try and except earlier, but this resulted in a lot of empty descriptions even though on the website the jobs have full descriptions.

Comment: Ah ya. I see what you mean. I’ll take another look at this to see if can square that way. May need to simply do something like put a delay in or user agent.